# remaining center after float for 2 divs

Tags: html, css, center, nav

i have tried many ways but it couldnt work yet. I have two divs on header, for header left is for logo and header right is for navs. So, i have to float it. but still i cant make it to the center of the website.

This is my code

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-center">
        <div id="headerleft">
            <h1> Hello </h1>
            <p> caption </p>
        </div>

        <div id="headerright">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="index.php"> HOME </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="work.php"> WORKS </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="cv.php"> CV </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="blog.php"> BLOG </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="contact.php"> CONTACT </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS..

```
 #header {
    height:100px;
    border-bottom:2px solid grey;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}

#header-center {
    margin:0 auto;
}

#headerleft {
    float:left;
}

#header h1 {
    padding:2px 15px;
    font-size:30px;
}

#header p {
    padding:2px 15px;
    font-size:20px;
}

#headeright {
    float:right;
}

#headerright ul li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:15px;
}


#menu li a {
    font-size: 15px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
}

#menu li:hover a {
    color:grey;
}
```

To be clear, you can have a look in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pdcPp/).

Anybody can find any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. What are you trying to centre? You've mentioned left and right floating, but what element needs to be centred?

Comment: #header-center, I guess.

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff But `header-center` is containing left and right, so I'm not exactly 100% what the intended layout is.

Comment: to center an element you have to give it a width

Comment: I'm trying to make #header-center on the center of the page no matter how width it is. header-left is for logo, and header-right is for navs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto;` works only if you also defined the width, so you should give a width for `#header-center`:

for example:

```
#header-center {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: If you set display:table; the element will take margin:0 auto; without having an explicitly set width. However, this solution introduces other potential problems, so if you can set a width, do so.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this???

```
#header {
    height:100px;
    border-bottom:2px solid grey;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}

#header-center {
    margin:0 auto;
}

#headerleft {
    float:left;
}

#header h1 {
    padding:2px 15px;
    font-size:30px;
}

#header p {
    padding:2px 15px;
    font-size:20px;
}

#headeright {
    float:right;
    width:500px;

}
#headerright ul{
margin:0 auto;  width:500px;
       padding: 35px;
}
#headerright ul li{

    list-style:none;
  float: left;
     width:100px;



#menu li a {
    font-size: 15px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
}

#menu li:hover a {
    color:grey;
}
```